# Can anyone explain this

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

This is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

I use storyboard and I am teaching an aprentice.

At the end of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions we should already have a rootViewController right?

Well,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:@"a08863b514ef09558ba82fec070cc7468fdbeeae"];
    [BGMDApplicationsPointers doThisAtStartup];
    [BGMDApplicationsPointers rootViewTabBarController].delegate=self;
    return YES;
}
```

I didn't see any rootViewController being assigned. I only set some delegate (my main code).

Looks like the project must have decided rootViewController from the story board. But where in the project it's specified where the rootViewController is or which story board to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story board loads the initial view controller as the root view controller. The information about which view controller has to be made the initial view controller is contained in the same story board. View controller that has an arrow pointing to it signifies it is the initial view controller.

Comment: And which story board the program should load?

Comment: In project settings ->Summary->iPhone/iPad deployment info you have the Main Storyboard settings, there you can specify which storyboard the main program has to load.